# Magento Admin Create Order needs to skip select Store

Tags: magento

Magento EE 1.12 with 30+ Stores.

When in Admin on a Customer Edit Page we have the option to Create Order. By default this will take us to a "Select store page even though the Current_Customer is assigned to only one store. Seems Store_Id is not carried. I have read a post about inserting store_id and Magento will skip this store selection step. (Here is a link to this post [Avoiding the select a store option when placing orders](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3239/avoiding-the-select-a-store-option-when-placing-orders))

I have been unsuccessful on getting Magento to skip this step.

My question would be if anyone has been successful on skipping the "Store Selection" page? If so, can you point me in the right direction on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go directly to the product selection part of the create admin order process by this url:

```
Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("adminhtml/sales_order_create",array("customer_id" => your_customer_id, "store_id"=> your_store_id));
```

You just have to call it by a button or by a form passing the store_id and customer_id parameters.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This Worked Perfectly. I did add this to getCreateOrderUrl() in Edit.php for the button Action, and also i needed to add if(!$store) to use the default.